# mysql queries to add simple prodcts in magento

Tags: mysql, magento

Any one can help me to insert 1000 products of one database table into magento

I have one database table of product i want to insert all products of this table into magento store using mysql queries

Database Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`title` text NOT NULL,
`author` text NOT NULL,
`isbn13` bigint(13) NOT NULL,
`isbn10` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`rank` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`pic` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`price` int(10) NOT NULL,
`publicationdate` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`publisher` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`desc1` text NOT NULL,
`cat` varchar(25) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: all answered over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984900/how-do-i-have-to-import-products-in-magento-using-a-direct-connection-to-the-dat and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323102/magento-products-import-from-database-using-sql-query  Soich woiks...

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your data goes in correctly, you probably should use the Magento import feature , the official tutorial is available [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-using-magentos-import-export-profiles).
If you attempt to do it via a direct mysql insert you may end up missing some of the EAV data that Magento requires...

If you need something a little faster, then you can use [Magmi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Main_Page) to import the data.
I am using Magmi on a daily basis to import/update around 3500 configurable and simple products without any issues.

Comment: @fogsy if you use magento, prestashop etc, then you shouldn't directly access the database. You should use the API because this is decoupled from the database, and supported. ... Of course using the database directly is going to be faster.

Comment: For those who have not been there, there is an easy answer. For those who've tried and failed, the looney hatch is a good home. For those who've tried and succeeded, Magmi is as close as it gets.